# UIWebView pdf content is no resized in iPhone 5 (4-inch)

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, uiwebview

I'm using UIWebView to load local 5 pages pdf file, the page content is perfect in iPhone (3.5 inch), but it's not resized appropriately in 4-inch, check the screen shot.
How can I fix it?
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you can fix it. UIWebView *scales down* pdf's to make them fit the iPhone screen, but it wont *stretch* them.

If the pdf is local as you say, you could always include 2 pdf files, one for iPhone 4inch and one for 3.5inch.

Comment: If you're right, UIWebView should make each page fit the iPhone 4-inch, but it isn't doing that in iPhone 4-inch, only 3.5-inch

Comment: It will not fit the 4 inch.. You will need to make another pdf with longer page lengths to fit the new screen RATIO of the 4-inch iPhone... The UIWebView WILL NOT stretch a pdf just to make it fit the page lengthways, it will however SCALE a pdf so it fits the page along the widths of the phone. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough above

Answer (score 1):

you can check the screen size for 4inch or 3.5inch

```
 CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568)
{
   //for iphone 5 
   //for 4 inch
}
else
{
  //for iphone 4
  //for 3.5 inch
}
```